# c: Ignore parent, child and DS_STORE files

Tags: c, file, directory

I am trying to create a program that goes through a directory and prints `"This is a directory"` for all sub-directories and this is a `"regular file"` for all text files/photos etc.

The problem is, when I go to do so, the parent, child and DS_STORE file and directories are shown.

I know there have been similar questions on this forum, but some of them are either too advanced for me or focus on other languages.

Just to be clear, I'm trying to iterate through a directory while ignoring the parent, child and DS_Store files/folders.

Here's what I have so far:

**all include/define statements**

```
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <errno.h>
#include    <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define BUFFERSIZE      4096
#define COPYMODE        0644
#define FILE_MODE   S_IRWXU

DIR *directory;
struct dirent *entry;
```

**Functions**

```
bool isaDie(struct dirent *aFile)

{
    char fileType = aFile->d_type;
    switch(fileType)
    {
        case DT_DIR:
            printf("this is a directory \n");
             return true;
            break;

        case DT_REG:

            printf("This is a regular file \n");
            return false;
        default: printf("Unknown file type \n");
  }       return false;
}



struct stat;

void goThoughFile( const char  *aFilePath )
{

directory = opendir(aFilePath);

    if(directory == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);

    }

else
{
    while( (entry = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", entry->d_name);

    isaDie(entry);
    }
  }
}
```

**main**

```
  int main()
{


    goThoughFile("somePathHere" );


    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Well, check the name at the top of the goThoughFile()  while loop and continue if the name matches any of those you don't want, "..". etc.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Thank you.